# Updated iPython: Make your own Mandelbrot image not appearing

Tags: python, ipython, interpolation, attributeerror, mandelbrot

---

This is my first question so I am not sure if the formatting is correct. I am reading the book Make Your Own Mandelbrot by Tariq Rashid using iPython (Jupyter Notebook). It seems that iPython has changed since this book was written so I have been tweaking the code in the book according to my limited understanding of Python. However, the image is not currently displaying. (There is just a blank graph.) The current error I am receiving is:
'AxesImage' object has no property 'interpolaton'

### This is my code:

```
import numpy
def mandel(c, maxiter):
    z = complex(0,0)
    for iteration in range(maxiter):
        z = (z*z) + c
        if abs(z) > 4:
            break
            pass
        pass
    return iteration
xvalues = numpy.linspace(-2.25, 0.75, 1000)
yvalues = numpy.linspace(-1.5, 1.5, 1000)
xlen = len(xvalues)
ylen = len(yvalues)
atlas = numpy.empty((xlen,ylen))
for ix in range(xlen):
    for iy in range(ylen):
        cx = xvalues[ix]
        cy = yvalues[iy]
        c = complex(cx, cy)
        atlas[ix,iy] = mandel(c,40)
        pass
    pass
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig= plt.figure(figsize=(18,18))
plt.imshow(atlas.T, interpolaton="nearest")
```

---

How do I fix this?

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_21768/3787280441.py in <module>
     24 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     25 fig= plt.figure(figsize=(18,18))
---> 26 plt.imshow(atlas.T, interpolaton="nearest")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in imshow(X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, filternorm, filterrad, resample, url, data, **kwargs)
   2901         filternorm=True, filterrad=4.0, resample=None, url=None,
   2902         data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2903     __ret = gca().imshow(
   2904         X, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, aspect=aspect,
   2905         interpolation=interpolation, alpha=alpha, vmin=vmin,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1359     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1360         if data is None:
-> 1361             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1362 
   1363         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in imshow(self, X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, filternorm, filterrad, resample, url, **kwargs)
   5603             aspect = rcParams['image.aspect']
   5604         self.set_aspect(aspect)
-> 5605         im = mimage.AxesImage(self, cmap, norm, interpolation, origin, extent,
   5606                               filternorm=filternorm, filterrad=filterrad,
   5607                               resample=resample, **kwargs)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in __init__(self, ax, cmap, norm, interpolation, origin, extent, filternorm, filterrad, resample, **kwargs)
    898         self._extent = extent
    899 
--> 900         super().__init__(
    901             ax,
    902             cmap=cmap,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in __init__(self, ax, cmap, norm, interpolation, origin, filternorm, filterrad, resample, **kwargs)
    255         self._imcache = None
    256 
--> 257         self.update(kwargs)
    258 
    259     def __getstate__(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in update(self, props)
   1060                     func = getattr(self, f"set_{k}", None)
   1061                     if not callable(func):
-> 1062                         raise AttributeError(f"{type(self).__name__!r} object "
   1063                                              f"has no property {k!r}")
   1064                     ret.append(func(v))

AttributeError: 'AxesImage' object has no property 'interpolaton'
```

Comment: Show the full error message as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo:

```
plt.imshow(atlas.T, interpolaton="nearest")
```

needs to be

```
plt.imshow(atlas.T, interpolation="nearest")
```

and

```
import numpy
def mandel(c, maxiter):
    z = complex(0,0)
    for iteration in range(maxiter):
        z = (z*z) + c
        if abs(z) > 4:
            break
            pass
        pass
    return iteration
xvalues = numpy.linspace(-2.25, 0.75, 1000)
yvalues = numpy.linspace(-1.5, 1.5, 1000)
xlen = len(xvalues)
ylen = len(yvalues)
atlas = numpy.empty((xlen,ylen))
for ix in range(xlen):
    for iy in range(ylen):
        cx = xvalues[ix]
        cy = yvalues[iy]
        c = complex(cx, cy)
        atlas[ix,iy] = mandel(c,40)
        pass
    pass
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig= plt.figure(figsize=(18,18))
plt.imshow(atlas.T, interpolation="nearest")
```

gives:

[image]